# PHP IF statements clashing for multiple rules

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I've got a textbox that I am using to do calculations with based on the code entered into it.  This code will have either a prefix or a suffix added to it.  My problem is that in one code, the prefix and suffix rules will clash and cause both actions to happen, when I only want the prefix action to happen.  Here's the code:

```
//get suffix and prefix from input box
$suffix = $inputbox[strlen($inputbox)-1];
$prefix = $inputbox[0];

if($inputbox!="" && $suffix=="L" or $suffix=="P" or $suffix="Y" or $suffix=="T")
{
//do this
}

if($inputbox!="" && $inputbox=="NT")
{
//do that
}
```

With the code as it is, the script is doing both, because the input box is NT and it also has a suffix of T.  What I want is to ignore the first rule, or put an operator in the first rule to say that it should only run if suffix is T and prefix is not N.

I know there is a simple way to do it, but it's almost 1am and I want to finish this before I retire to my bed!

Comment: I counter the downvote with an upvote muahaha, power to the upvoters. good luck~

Comment: Thanks man.  I have never done programming before and am learning as I go. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So switch the order and use an `else`. Also, you have a redundant rule, which I've removed. Also, your `&&` has a higher precedence than your `or`s; but it's also unnecessary. You've also mixed in an assignment with the condition. (Maybe get some rest?)

```
// Get suffix and prefix from input box
$suffix = $inputbox[strlen($inputbox)-1];
$prefix = $inputbox[0];

if($inputbox == "NT") {
    //do that
} elseif($suffix == "L" or $suffix == "P" or $suffix == "Y" or $suffix == "T") {
    //do this
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Used this and it's now working.  I'm a first time coder and have only ever used HTML and CSS so PHP is totally new to me.  I know my code is probably not the greatest, but I'm learning as I go.  What does it mean to mix an assignment with the condition?  :/

Comment: @IanNuttall: You had an `=` mixed in with the `==`.

Answer (score 3):

i didnt understand exactly what you were trying to do, but try this:

```
 if($inputbox!="" ){
 //get suffix and prefix from input box
    $suffix = $inputbox[strlen($inputbox)-1];

    $suffixes = array("L","P","Y","T");
    if($inputbox=="NT") {
        //do that
    } else if(in_array($suffix, $suffixes)){
        //do this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want one action or another to happen, you probably want to use an `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
$suffix = $inputbox[strlen($inputbox)-1];
$prefix = $inputbox[0];

if($suffix == 'T' and $prefix <> 'N') :
```

Answer (score 0):

First check for the special case "NT", then for all the others:

```
//get suffix and prefix from input box
$suffix = $inputbox[strlen($inputbox)-1];
$prefix = $inputbox[0];

if($inputbox!="" && $inputbox=="NT")
{
  //do that
} else if ($inputbox!="" && $suffix=="L" or $suffix=="P" or $suffix="Y" or $suffix=="T")
{
  //do this
}
```